# How can I automatically push Eventbrite events to Facebook?

Tags: json, facebook, eventbrite

There is a manual step in Eventbrite (Add To Facebook) that allows me to do this. I want to automate this step using the API, so once the Eventbrite event is published, it also publishes it to Facebook.

Comment: there is no api for creating events on facebook

Comment: Okay, but how does Eventbrite do it?

Comment: maybe they have a special deal with facebook, who knows. but didn´t you say it is a manual step anyway?